# groff "me" macro, but use sans serif font for headings etc

Tags: fonts, groff

I'm learning troff for typesetting documents. I found the `me` macros nice and beautiful out of the box and want to avoid `mom`. `me` defaults everything to serif fonts which is ugly for larger text like the cover page and headings. How can I change the font to something sans serif for those passages?

I tried `.ft H` and other `.ft` commands, non of those seemed to do anything (they worked with `ms`/`mom`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `me` macros in `groff` use the following font positions for various types of text:

1. Normal text font
2. (unused?)
3. Title font *and* section font

The macros will switch to use the fonts loaded at these positions when setting the text for e.g. a section title, so the `.ft` macro would be ineffective. You would still be able to use e.g.

```
.sh 1 "\f(HBSection title"
```

to switch to a bold sans-serif font for the section title, but the numbering of the section would still be using a serif font.

The `me` macro file sets up a number of parameters that they use for things like fonts and point sizes etc., so much of the interesting stuff is quite easy to modify by just changing a few number registers and things like that, but this is unfortunately not covered by the `groff_me(7)` manual.  It's also well hidden in the `e.tmac` macro file (due to the file having had comments stripped out of it).  I had to read the original (un-stripped) `e.tmac-u` file in the `groff` source distribution to figure this out:

```
.\"             *** PARAMETRIC INITIALIZATIONS ***
.
.
.rr x
.nr $v \n(.v00+\n(.sp-1/\n(.sp  \" vs as % of ps for .sz request
.nr $V \n($v                    \" same for displays & footnotes
.nr hm 4v                       \" header margin
.nr tm 7v                       \" top margin
.nr bm 6v                       \" bottom margin
.nr fm 3v                       \" footer margin
.nr tf 3                        \" title font: (real) Times Bold
.nr tp 10                       \" title point size
.hy 6
.nr bi 4m                       \" indent for blocks
.nr pi 5n                       \" indent for paragraphs
.nr pf 1                        \" normal text font
.nr pp 10                       \" normal text point size
.nr qi 4n                       \" indent for quotes
.nr qp -1                       \" down one point
.nr ii 5n                       \" indent for .ip's and .np's
.nr $m 1                        \" max number of columns
.nr $s 4n                       \" column separation
.nr sf 3                        \" section font -- Times Bold
.nr sp 10                       \" section title pointsize
.nr ss 12p                      \" section prespacing
.nr si 0                        \" section indent
```

To change the section and title font to a bold sans-serif font, use

```
.fp 3 HB
```

to load the `HB` font into position 3. This would then be picked up by the `.sh` macro and others.

Example:

```
.fp 3 HB
.bp
.sh 1 "Heading 1"
.lp
Text text.
.sh 2 "Heading 2"
.lp
Text text.
```

This would generate

[image: Rendered PDF output from groff]

Comment: looks promising. I will try once I'm done with my work. Thank you!

Comment: It works great. Now I also have a much better understanding about fonts in groff. Thank you

Comment: That's very useful, thanks. Some experimenting suggests that font 2 is for equations, by the way.